# ItemContainerStyle overriding Generic style

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol, itemcontainerstyle

I'm referencing ExpressionDark.xaml from my App.xaml, which is working fine, however when I try to use an ItemContainerStyle in an ItemsControl, the items in the ItemsControl revert to the basic styling.

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10">
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.Items>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Error}" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Username,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Password,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}"></TextBox>
        <Button VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Command="{Binding SignInCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding CanSignIn}" Content="Sign In"></Button>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Username}"></TextBox>
    </ItemsControl.Items>
</ItemsControl>
```

I'm only trying to find a good control for vertical styling (easily adding margin between items), so maybe there's a better way that doesn't override the style specified in App.xaml.

TIA

Answer (score 2):

If you specify an "*in place*" style, it is considered as a completely new style.
Due to that the default style from **ExpressionDark.xaml** is forgotton for that element.

What you have to do to avoid this is: Refer to the base style with BasedOn=

```
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
   <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource Existing}">
      <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
   </Style>
</ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Find the corresponding default style for your control. And replace `Existing` with the Resource-Key from **ExpressionDark.xaml**. You can identify it because it will have the proper `TargetType` property set:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}"> x:Key=...
```

Where ListBoxItem is your control in use (to be restyled)

You may consider using `ListBox` instead of `ItemsControl` as it has `ListBoxItem` as container.

Answer (score 0):

They way you use the margin is fine, but when you use a different style then the one in the `App.xaml`, it duffently won't use the one in `App.xaml`.

This is the way it works in WPF, the control uses the style "closest" to it, and since you are writing this style directly into the control, it uses that style.

you can make a new style in the `app.xaml` with the 'BaseOn' property based on the `ExpressionDark.xaml`, but you'll add the:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: But what property would this be 'BasedOn'? I wouldn't have thought that ExpressionDark.xaml specifies any ItemContainerStyle?

Comment: Hmm, maybe i misunderstood you, i thought that ExpressionDark.xaml was a style...
if it is, or if it contains a style, you can give that style a key, and the "BasedOn" would get that key.
then you will add the item container property setter.